# using scikit-learn cosine_similarity on Dask array- python

Tags: python, scikit-learn, dask

I have Dask to handle big array of vectors that cant fit in memory and using scikit-learn cosine_similarity to compute cosine similarity between those vector i.e:

```
import dask.array as da
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity
vectors = da.from_array(vectors, 10000)
sims_mat = cosine_similarity(vectors)
```

Works fine but I am not sure if in this way I have any benefits of using Dask or should I look for cosine similarity function for dask arrays

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion this should be fine, because if you check the documentation of both **dask** and **sklearn**, you will find out that both are built on top **numpy**, which uses parallel processing.

If you really want to use only dask you could check this repo out:
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/dask-distance

It includes a cosine similarity function.