# Dash - Applying cosine similarity to a column of arrays

Tags: dask, cosine-similarity

I'm looking to leverage dash to calculate pairwise cosine similarity.

Here is the schema of my dataframe:

```
 |-- embeddings: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: float (containsNull = true)
 |-- id: long (nullable = true)
```

Ultimately, I would like to generate an NXN matrix. I've tried the following:

Based on [this stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49282800/using-scikit-learn-cosine-similarity-on-dask-array-python), I attempted to use the sklearn method.

```
cosine_similarity(df['embeddings'])

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

Next, I tried to use the [dask_distance function](https://dask-distance.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dask_distance.html#dask_distance.cosine)

```
dd_cosine_sim = dask_distance.cosine(df['embeddings'], df['embeddings'])

dd_cosine_sim.compute()

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

I thought it was interesting that I'm getting the same error but I'm having trouble understanding why. The arrays are constructed properly and there are no issues when running this on vanilla python.

Any help would be much appreciated. I have a feeling this might have to do with my limited understanding of distributed computing.

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce this, could you please share a minimal example as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example